# Martingale Difference Sequence CLT

Tags: normal-distribution, asymptotics, central-limit-theorem, martingale

Could you provide me with the proof of the following:

$$n^{-1/2} \cdot\sum_t a_{t-j}e_t$$ converges to normal distribution as $n$ goes infinity by martingale difference sequence CLT where $a_t = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \psi_je_{t-j}$ with $\sum_{j=0}^\infty |\psi_j|< \infty$ and $e_t$ is i.i.d with $\mathbb{E}(e_t)=0$, $Var(e_t)= \sigma^2$

Comment: It might be worth providing the index of the first summation (t or j?) in order to make the question clearer.

Comment: I have edited as you wish. To be honest whatever I have asked so far here I can not get sufficient response. Please spare your time towards the aim of forum.@Richard Hardy, always will be waiting for your valuable return.

Comment: Please could you help me about my question? mybe @Richard Hardy?